# Non breaking space in XAML vs. code

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, whitespace

This works fine, and correctly inserts non-breaking spaces into the string:

```
<TextBlock Text="Non&#160;Breaking&#160;Text&#160;Here"></TextBlock>
```

But what I really need is to replace spaces with non-breaking spaces during data binding. So I wrote a simple value converter that replaces spaces with "`&#160;`". It does indeed replace spaces with "`&#160;`" but "`&#160;`" is displayed literally instead of showing as a non-breaking space. This is my converter:

```
public class SpaceToNbspConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString().Replace(" ", "&#160;");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Does anybody know why it works in XAML, but not in code?

Comment: This is great, I didn't know how to do non-breaking space before. Thanks for the question! It answered my own question!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried `return value.ToString().Replace(' ', System.Convert.ToChar(160));` ?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Do you know why it is necessary to work with char rather than string?

Comment: It should work with the string override too. Just cast the ToChar() to string afterwards.

Answer (score 25):

In code the syntax for escaping Unicode chars is different than in XAML:

```
XAML: &#160;
C#:   \x00A0
```

So this should have worked in code:

```
return value.ToString().Replace(" ", "\xA0");
```

Comment: Great. I needed this to tweak a <Run> inside a <TextBlock>. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

The reason Char is working and string is not - is that the string is escaped when rendered.