# Set TextBlock to preserve white space at the beginning and at the end?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textblock

### EDIT:

The code below actually works as I want - this question a little misleading. Please ignore it.

---

Normally when I set `Text` property of `TextBlock` like this:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = "     Hello World ";
```

The whitespace at the beginning and at the end of text are not shown. The text shown by `TextBlock` is only `Hello World`. How can I set `TextBlock` to display them (i.e., not remove the whitespace)? Am I missing some property?

Answer (score 58):

In this case you don't need to use `xml:space="preserve"`

```
<TextBlock xml:space="preserve" Text="     Hello world!    " />
```

WILL display the whitespaces, however

```
<TextBlock>    Hello world!    </TextBlock>
```

won't.

Comment: Holy crap. xml:space="preserve" is quite handy. Have a +1

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for extending TextDecorations, the space at the beginning is there and decorated, but the text at the end is undecorated (it's still there though). It will work if you use [non-breaking spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943767/non-breaking-space-in-xaml-vs-code) though.

Answer (score 9):

Re: "I just hope you are not using this to align your text. There are many other more elegant methods to do so."

Sounds like you might want to use the Padding property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.padding(VS.85).aspx.

See also the various alignment & margin properties.

Comment: I agree with Rob, however, I can see the usefulness of xml:space="preserve". For example, if you are using ViewBox, margin or padding are hard to use as the font size may vary (hence the space size).

Answer (score 6):

set the xml:space property to preserve in your XAML, i assume you are using WPF

```
<TextBlock xml:space="preserve" Text="     Hello world!    " />
```

EDIT: It is sometimes easier to do things in XAML. I just hope you are not using this to align your text. There are many other more elegant methods to do so.

Comment: Sorry but -1. The white space is not removed because of XAML - the same think will happen if you set it in code. I intentionally gave example in code. I guess this is done by `TextBlock` itself.

Comment: So sorry. You are right. In code it does not trim it. I cannot cancel my downvote until you edit your answer :( So if you care about votes please edit your answer just a little so I can replace downvote by upvote.

Comment: I would like to see if you can set xml:space="preserve" in code or if that attribute could be set to a run.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the Text= property. This also works:

```
<TextBlock xml:space="preserve">Staff Contact Details        <Hyperlink>Click here</Hyperlink></TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using the [`Run` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.run?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="    "/>
    Hello world!
</TextBlock>
```