# C# + Windows Phone => TextBlock, preserve whitespaces?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am creating an application where I need to loop through a series of text lines that may contain whitespace.

I build up a string by doing `my_string += the_line_to_add` and update the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` with the final string.

Pretty simple actually, however, a line that looks like this:

```
"a          b   c"
```

will end up as follows:

```
"a b c"
```

I don't want all of those spaces to be removed though. I want the line to keep the extra spaces and remain unchanged:

```
"a          b   c"
```

The `TextBlock` is created programmatically and added into a `StackPanel`. I looked at the different properties but just can't figure it out.

Comment: Are there tabs involved in this?  Or is it just spaces?

Comment: Nevermind, that shouldn't matter.  The bug with tabs I'm thinking of only affects the RichTextBox.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. I think I have figured it out now, but I had to read it more than once. Please improve the wording so that it can't be misinterpreted. State what you *want* to happen clearly.

Comment: Hi, sorry english is not my native language. I'll try to rewrite it.

Comment: Have you been able to verify the value of the `Text` property in the debugger?  Also, posting the code where `Text` is being set might help.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934031/set-textblock-to-preserve-white-space-at-the-beginning-and-at-the-end

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'd approach this problem differently. I wouldn't use whitespaces in a string to layout the text. If you need 3 string in the screen add 3 textboxes and set Margin proprety. This depends on the input text, but if there will be too many whitespaces the text will be out of the screen.

Alternatively, you can use [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to format the text.